# Enhance Showdown.js table code so that it supports left/right alignment of table headers

Tags: javascript, github-flavored-markdown, showdown

Im using [Showdown.js](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown) and have implemented the tables extensions and got it working for normal tables.

The extension does not support 'Github Flavoured Markdown' for header alignment.

Example:

```
|Normal Heading | Right Aligned |
| ------------- | ------------: |
```

Please help me with what code I can include in my [table.js](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown/blob/master/src/extensions/table.js) file to add this support.

I found similar code in marked.js [here](https://github.com/chjj/marked/blob/master/lib/marked.js#L92).

Comment: A [new issue](https://github.com/showdownjs/table-extension/issues/2) as been opened for this request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Showdown >= 1.2.0 now has built in support for tables (with alignment) in core. You just need to activate it in the options:

```
var conv = new showdown.Converter({tables: true});
```